# frida - defpackage class not list in android

Tags: frida

I found some classes in defpackage directory but it not list out with below code:

```
log("load script")
Java.perform(function() {
    log("load java")
    var clzlst = []
    Java.enumerateLoadedClasses({
        onMatch: function(clzname) {
            clzlst.push(clzname)
        },
        onComplete: function(e) {
            console.log("<<<<onComplete");
        }
    });
    log(clzlst.length)
    clzlst.forEach(function (clzname) {
        if (clzname.includes("abcd")) {
            log("found clz:" + clzname) // this line not been hitted.
        }
        });

    var hook = Java.use("abcd");
    var methods = hook.class.getDeclaredMethods();
    hook.$dispose();
 
    methods.forEach(function (method) {
        var name = method.toString();
        log(name) // this line hitted
    });
});

function log(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
}
```

The loaded list classes not include target class (e.g. abcd), but if I call Java.use("abcd"), I can access that class successfully.

I guess that class maybe still not being loaded! how can I list all classes even if it's not been loaded?

Comment: There are ways to dynamically load Java classes, one of them is `DexClassLoader`

Comment: As the method name `enumerateLoadedClasses` indicates you are getting all loaded classes. Java classes that has not been used yet are not loaded, even if they are present in the main dex file(s) of the APK. You can verify that by first calling `Java.use("abcd")` and then enumerating all classes. Then the class `abcd` should be listed.

Comment: Try looking into the smali code of these classes, and check for their name. One modification I know of with defpackage is that the bundles are named only with their suffix, e.g. `defpackage.abcd` becomes `abcd`.